# How are closed captions (CEA-608) included in ProRes 422 HQ?

Tags: video, video-processing

I want to know, how to manually burn subtitles in ProRes 422 HQ. For example, CEA-608 in AVC(H.264) are presented as SEI units of NAL. What about Apple ProRes 422? I didn't find any info.

Comment: Nothing useful [from research](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=prores+422+hq+subtitles)? This is a forum for **programming** questions so your question might be off-topic.

Comment: What is the file format? Is it *.mov? Do you have a short example that you can post somewhere?